# Why do my custom membership and role provider work locally, but fail after deployment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a custom membership and role provider to leverage the authentication and authorization built into ASP.NET MVC 4. Everything had been going smoothly during development of my application until I tried deploying it to a test environment.

Launching the application in Debug mode from Visual Studio works perfectly fine. However, I then use Visual Studio's one click deployment to load my application into an instance of IIS running on my development machine. I am able to load the application in my browser, but authentication no longer works. Using Fiddler, I see that a cookie is sent back, but I am unable to access portions of the site that are restricted using [Authorize] attributes.

Below is a relevant snippet from my web.config.

```
<membership defaultProvider="PonosMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="PonosMembershipProvider" type="Ponos.Identity.PonosMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/Ponos" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="Ponos.Identity.PonosRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/Ponos" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Additionally, I set the application name in both custom provider with logic as follows:

```
public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Ponos";
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Additionally, after attaching to the running instance of IIS, I see that the information entered into the form passes validation, but that no access is granted to pages that have restricted authorized access.

Also, the database on being used for the deployment is populated with the same values as the development database.

Why wouldn't the providers work after deployment when they are functioning fine in the debugging environment?

Comment: You did create the Roles on the deployment server?

Comment: I did, the the populated deployment tables match the development tables.

Comment: I assume no proxies are in the mix?  We've seen auth cookies get tossed by certain proxy configurations.

Comment: None insofar as I can tell. I only run Fiddler once in a while to verify whether or not an auth cookie is actually being returned.

Comment: If you are using sql, do a query on apsnet_applications and make sure that it's not creating different applicationName.  It looks like you named your application so it should be fine but double check just in case.

Comment: Why you have set "/Ponos" and "Ponos". Why they are not the same ? And where are you set the cookie for authentication ?

Comment: "authentication no longer works" I don't know what this means. Are you getting an exception?

Comment: @o_q No exception is thrown, but I am redirected to the default page whenever I attempt to access a place that is protected at the controller level with an [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: @atbebtg That table doesn't exist in my database. I wrote custom providers that wrap entity framework to use the Membership and Role functionality of ASP.NET.

Comment: does IIS have permission to the membership database?

Comment: @o_q We're creating this app as a proof of concept right now, so it uses a connection string that contains the needed credentials.

Comment: I would suggest to debug the application that is hosted in IIS (you could configure that in the properties of your project). Then I would set a breakpoint in your roleprovider and check which roles are returned from your database using your Entity Framework context. By the way: It is always a good idea to host the application in IIS,  once configured you don't need Cassini any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was only showing up when my deployed server was accessed directly by its IP. When I added a hosts entry mapping a domain to the IP and subsequently set the same domain in my auth cookie the issue was resolved.

I'm not sure why I couldn't access the cookie if the domain was an IP address, but this did fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"I see that the information entered into the form passes validation, but that no access is granted to pages that have restricted authorized access."

seems like permissions problem!